# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android

Hello i am getting error in the follwing code as- **"Value at reachus of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"**..I am getting values for all other `Json object` but getting error at reachus object..how to convert `java.lang.String` to the `JsonObject`?please give the solution..Thanks

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(Constants.sercall.response_str);
JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject;
jObj2 = jObj.getJSONObject("value");

JSONObject jObj6=new JSONObject;
jObj6=jObj2.getJSONObject("reachus");
if (jObj6.has("Email")) {
activitycontactinfo = jObj6.getString("Email");
activitycontactinfo = URLDecoder.decode(activitycontactinfo);
activitycontactinfo= activitycontactinfo.replace("%20", " ");
activitycontactinfo = Constants.convertToUpperCase(activitycontactinfo);
}
```

Here is my Json:

```
    {"value":{
        "classdetails":{},
        "other_activities_details":"",
        "activitydetails":{},
        "youlearn":"",
        "reachus":{
            "Email":[
                "varsha.b%40wiztango.com"
            ],
            "facebook":"http%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252FVarsha%2520Borhade",
            "website":"http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wiztango.com",
            "linkedin":"http%253A%252F%252Fwww.linkedin.com%252Fborhadevarsha",
            "twitter":"http%253A%252F%252Fwww.twitter.com%252Fvarshaborhade",
            "phone number":[
                {
                    "value":"678698",
                    "meta":"varsha"
                }
            ]
        },
        "spons_speak_host":"",
        "categories":"",
        "display_blocks":[],
        "display_user_information":[],
        "display_content_information":[],
        "display_published_contents":[],
        "faculty_published_contents":[],
        "open_url_enrollment_users_list":"0",
        "total_participants":[],
        "display_agenda_information":[],
        "faculty_published_agenda":[],
        "display_published_agenda_ids":[]
    }

}
```

Comment: your JSON is not valid. hope "Email":[
                "varsha.b%40wiztango.com"
            ], here you are getting problem

Comment: post your code and logcat stack trace

Comment: But when i will remove this if block of Email then also i am getting that error..I am getting this error only for "Reachus" array not for other array.

Comment: this site http://jsonlint.com/ told me that your Json is valid.. problem is probably elsewhere

Comment: see use http://json.parser.online.fr/ to see your json structure. Reachus should be an array

Comment: i had gone through the json.parser.online.fr. the json structure i am giving in my question is from json.parser.online.fr..rechus is JsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

This code enables you to access the 'reachus' field and email:--
Use this code:--

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject reachusJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("value")
                .getJSONObject("reachus");
        JSONArray emailArray = reachusJson.getJSONArray("Email");
        Log.e("email ", emailArray.getString(0));
```

Comment: Sorry but I am getting the same error after adding this code.

Comment: not possible i checked on my machine before posting here. pls check your json twice as i implemented this code on the json you posted

Comment: yes the code is right,but dont know why i am getting the same error..ok i will try and find out where is the mistake..thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

First, please use more meaningful names for your variables, then look at the structure of your JSON, it's:

JSONObject (main) -> JSONObject (value) -> JSONObject (reachus) -> JSONArray (Email) -> String

So:

1. Get your JSOBObject

   ```
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Constants.sercall.response_str);
   ```
2. Get JSONObject for "value":

   ```
   JSONObject valueJson = json.getJSONObject("value");
   ```
3. Get JSONObject for "reachus":

   ```
   JSONObject reachusJson = json.getJSONObject("reachus");
   ```
4. Because "Email" is JSONArray, first get JSONArray, then get the first string (assuming there is one):

   ```
   if (reachusJson.has("Email")) {
       JSONArray emailJsonArray = reachusJson.getJSONArray("Email");

       //rest of your code
       activitycontactinfo = emailJsonArray.getString(0);
       activitycontactinfo = URLDecoder.decode(activitycontactinfo);
       activitycontactinfo = activitycontactinfo.replace("%20", " ");
       activitycontactinfo = Constants.convertToUpperCase(activitycontactinfo);
   }
   ```

You might want to add some checks in case Email array is empty.